# Spring/JUnit/Mockito: How do I inject a value that is @Value annotated into a mocked bean?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4

Background:

- Java 8 (1.8.0_201)
- Spring Boot
- Mockito (2.23.4)

I have a number of JUnit tests written for our software application and am in the middle of refactoring/fixing test failures due to modifications to the code base.

I have run into a problem I don't know how to solve. I'll include code snippets to hopefully illustrate what I have.

The problem is that a test fails with a NPE because a mocked bean's constructor argument is null. The argument is injected with a value (in the regular run-time environment) via a `@Value` annotation. I don't know how to provide that argument a value in the unit test.

Examples:

In the SUT class:

```
@Value("${logsDir}${file.separator}${service.name}_${service.id}_${service.container.type}_stats.json")
private String statsFilePath;
...
  @Override
  public void initialize() throws RSTServiceException {
    statsWriter = new StatsWriter<>(new StatsSerializer(ServiceStats.class), statsFilePath);
  }
```

In `StatsWriter.java`:

```
  public StatsWriter(StdSerializer<T> serializer, String filePath) throws RSTServiceException {
    File statsFile = new File(filePath);
  }
```

In the unit test:

```
  @Test
  public void testInitialize() {
    try {
      // Exercise SUT.
      service.initialize();
    } catch (RSTServiceException e) {
      fail(e.getMessage());
    }
    ...
  }
```

So, in the unit test, `statsFilePath` is null and the call to the `File` constructor fails with a NPE. How do I provide a non-null value to this field?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which class is mocked? And which constructor argument is null?

Comment: or [How do I mock an autowired @Value field in Spring with Mockito?](//stackoverflow.com/q/23162777)

Comment: Your testing issue here show why field injection is flawed. You should consider refactoring your code to use constructor injection instead.

Comment: I tweaked my google search parameters and found the referenced SO posting. Thanks for all of the quick responses. D'oh!